# Remove Script tag in production website with defer tag

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I want to remove remote js and load my local js in one production website.

So I use following userscript

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         TV full screen
// @match        https://example.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
    const script =  document.querySelector('script[src^="/static/bundles/main"]');
  if (!script ) {
    return;
  }
  observer.disconnect();
  script .remove();
  console.log('SRC removed');
   document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = "https://localhost/tv/my.js";



})
  .observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Following is the code present in production website

```
<script defer crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundles/main.js" ></script>
```

since there is defer code in script tag , still the actual source is getting executed , eventhough tag is removed..How do I completely remove that script tag and stop execution and load my local file.

Comment: It is useless to delete the script tag if the script is loaded it is already running.

Comment: Yes, how to delete before script tag loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the selector changing the line:

```
const script =  document.querySelector('script[src^="/static/bundles/main_chart"]');
```

with:

```
const script =  document.querySelector('script[src^="/static/bundles/main.js"]');
```

Comment: Sorry , that was typo , tag is removed in webpage , but still js is executed.

Answer (score 0):

May be Like This:

```
 var myScript = document.createElement('script');         

 if (location.hostname === "localhost" || location.hostname === "127.0.0.1"){
    myScript.src = '/path/to/my_LOCAL_Script...';
 }else{
    myScript.src = '/path/to/my_REMOTE_Script...';
 }

 document.head.appendChild(myScript);
```

Comment: Hi , what is the difference ?

Comment: document.querySelector (...) searches in the loaded document

Comment: How do I change source before dom is loaded.

Comment: It’s easier to load either some scripts or others. Depending on hostname.

Comment: still not working , original code is still executed.